# Javascript in popup

Tags: javascript, php

How do I get this script (Checking email address in DB):

```
   $("#engemail").keyup(function (e) {
     var engemail = $(this).val();
     var input=$(this);
     var re = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
     var is_email=re.test(input.val());

       if(is_email){
         $("#engemail-result").html('');
     $.post('includes/pub/email.php', {'engemail':engemail}, function(data) {

         console.log(engemail);
           if(data == '1'){
             $("#ny_button").attr("disabled", true);
             $('#engemail').css('border', '3px #c0392b solid');
             $("#engemail-result").html('  kan ikke godkendes?');
           } else {
           $("#ny_button").attr("disabled", false);
           $('#engemail').css('border', '3px #2ecc71 solid');
           $("#engemail-result").html(' er godkendt!');
         }
           });
       } else {
         $("#ny_button").attr("disabled", true);
         $('#engemail').css('border', '3px #c0392b solid');
         $("#engemail-result").html('  findes ikke i vores system?');

       }
                     });
```

to work in this pop up ??

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

     var trigger = document.querySelector('#js-overlay-trigger');

     trigger.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    novicell.overlay.create({
      'selector': trigger.getAttribute('data-element'),
      'class': 'selector-overlay',
      "onCreate": function() { console.log('created'); },
      "onLoaded": function() { console.log('loaded'); },
      "onDestroy": function() { console.log('Destroyed'); }

    });

     });




    });
     }

   });
```

Here the Popup/Html:

```
<div class="overlay-content" id="js-overlay-content" style="display: none;">
    <h1 class="font-weight-5">Denne popper upper</h1>
    <p>Indtast din email (som du brugte, da du oprettede din konto hos os.).</p>

  <form class="form-horizontal" id="sendkode"  method="post" onsubmit="return doit()">


    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
      <label for="email">Din email<span id="engemail-result"> </span> </label>
      <input name="engemail" type="text" class="form-control" id="engemail" placeholder="Email adresse" required autofocus>
    </div>


     <br>
     <div class="form-group">
           <button type="submit" id="ny_button" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
     </div>

 </form>
</div>
```

I'm not as strong yet in javascript, so hope for some help and some advice here. The script works fine in a "regular" modal popup, there is some good advice :-)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you explain what is your intention? Without knowing what you exactly want to do it is difficult to determine what "works" means.

Comment: After popup, i have a form to check a email in database, thats not working, no checking via ajax or javascript seems not to take effect in popup?

Answer (score 0):

Where is this script:

```
$("#engemail").keyup(f...
```

is located?
it should be below the html, so that engemail input tag will have sufficient time to be rendered in the DOM.

Comment: I have chosen to drop the project and make the form as a page without popup, thanks for input!